# How we can read xml file with jquery from database (postgres)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, postgresql

Hi I am working on jquery and xml . I am new on this . I did some work on jquery and xml . Actually I read xml file with jquery and populate it on front end . But now I write this xml file in database . But I don't know How I read xml from database following my code represent read a xml file , please anyone help me What I can change in this code for read database xml .

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'file.xml',
        async: false,
        success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('Tab').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('URL');
                var tab = $(this).attr('TabName');

                $("ul").append("<li><a href="+ id +">"+ tab +"</li>");

            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: please anyone help me !

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a [parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) function. Try modifying your code to:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'file.xml',
        async: false,
        success: function(xml) {

            $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));

            $xml.find('Tab').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('URL');
                var tab = $(this).attr('TabName');

                $("ul").append("<li><a href="+ id +">"+ tab +"</li>");

            });

        }
    });
```